# PHPmailer is overriding the domain when sending an email

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, multisite

I'm seeing an unexpected behaviour when sending emails from my WordPress Multisite installation. The thing is that at some point the domain of the "From" address is being swapped with the CNAME where my Multisite is located. So, instead of being send from **wordpress@mydomain.com** they're sent from **wordpress@cname**

I've already checked with some logs in **wp-includes/pluggable.php** and the "From" address is **wordpress@mydomain.com** when used in `$phpmailer->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name, false );` ; So I suppose there might be some configuration off that's making phpmailer override the domain, but I still haven't figured out what's wrong.

Some extra info:

- I'm running the multiste in subdomain mode.
- This behaviour is happening in all of the subsites.
- WP version is 4.9.8

Comment: It’s very likely the problem is your mail service. For example gmail completely ignores any from address you provide and uses your account address instead - that sounds like the behaviour you’re seeing.

Comment: @Synchro Nope, I'm sure it isn't the mail service since I've tried at least two of them.

Comment: Don't assume, check - set `$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 2` and look at what's in the `MAIL FROM` command. If that contains what you expect, you know it's your mail server that's changing it.